# Wamp Pear http/request2

Tags: php, http, wamp, pear, require-once

I have this line of code in my php file :

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
```

I have installed pear and the installation was successful and I have Request2.php file on my HTTP directory of pear on my wamp. I have put my php file on my www folder but when I run it I still get this message :

> Warning: require_once(HTTP/Request2.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\php\phptest.php on line 3

I don't get why I still get this error , is there a mistake in addressing the file or something else. I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.
thanks very much

Comment: "I have `request2.php` on my `http` directory" but the path you are requesting is `HTTP/Request2.php`. File names are case sensitive.

Comment: It was the mistake on the question , I've done it right on the system. edited to the correct ones.

Comment: try require_once('../HTTP/Request2.php');  the ".." goes back one directory

Comment: changed to ../HTTP/Request2.php and I still get the error.

Comment: is there a file `C:/wamp/www/php/HTTP/Request2.php` here?

Comment: No Requet2.php is in "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear\HTTP"

Comment: You need to check your include path - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112866/setup-include-path-for-pear-on-wamp http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.modifyingphpini

Comment: The pear folder is already added to the php.ini file. 
include_path=".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a script out of `C:\wamp\www\php\phptest.php` then I am assuming you are using the CLI i.e. running a script from the command line.

The CLI gets its php.ini file from `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` i.e. not the same php.ini file that is edited when you use the wampmanager menu system to edit `php.ini`

Make the change to your `include_path` in `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` and see if that solves your problems.

You can ask PHP where it is looking for its ini file by doing this:-

```
C:\>d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php --ini
```

Which should show something like this

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

P.S. Dont be tempted to put a php.ini file in the `C:\Windows` folder.

Comment: No , I'm not trying to run the script from command line. I did "php --ini" and it returned the same result as you've mentioned. here's the php.ini file : https://app.box.com/s/dldofu4yhq3izdchc2zj

Comment: You could try removing the `HTTP` from `include_path=".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear\HTTP"` that will probably fix it.

Comment: Try creating a file with just `<?php phpinfo()` inside it - put it in your web folder and then visit with your browser - check the include paths listed there and double check they are correct.