# XMLdiff for php installation

Tags: php, xmldiff

I am trying to install xml diff ; https://github.com/mmacia/XMLdiff and i have not managed yet to make it work.Whenever i run any test example,i get

> Fatal error: Interface 'PHPUnit_Framework_Test' not found in
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php on line 85

Has anyone managed to install and use the library.I am using xampp on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem has to do with PHPUnit's `Autoloader.php` not being included. This file sets the php `spl_autoloadspl_register` function which is responsible for loading in interfaces and classes like `PHPUnit_Framework_Test`.

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091862/getting-phpunit-working-include-path-not-set-correctly), you have to include the autoloader file manually. Without knowing more about your set-up and how that particular library works, I would say do something like this in the appropriate file(s):

```
// define phpunit path
if ( ! defined('PHPUNIT_PATH')) {
    // define an absolute path to your PHPUnit dir
    // CHECK THIS, i'm not good with php on windows:
    define('PHPUNIT_PATH','C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit');
}

// Then include the autoloader like this:
include PHPUNIT_PATH.'Autoloader.php';
```

I hope this helps you or anyone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Check execution flags for `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\Framework\Test.php`

The file needs to be executable by the user who is launching tests (probably you).