# Executing path for PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have installed `PHPunit` using `composer`. The application has unit test cases. from my project folder when i do a "`phpunit`" it gives me an error saying `phpunit` not found..but if i do a `"./vendor/bin/phpunit"` it will work.  Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: [Here][1] Is an other Question which can help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091862/getting-phpunit-working-include-path-not-set-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add PHPUnit to your path.  Include the ./vendor/bin/phpunit into your PATH environment (to be searched when looking for programs) in your OS.

Comment: It should not have to be.  You would have 1 PHPUnit, and test all your projects with it.  Relative paths may still be added to your PATH environment, if needed.  Also, I believe you can add PHPUnit to the include path in the Bootstrap.php file, in case you want to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got tired of fiddling with PATHs on all my machines, so I wrote a small tool that makes composer behave a bit more like PEAR did:

https://github.com/flack/poser

You can use it to install Composer packages globally by running:

```
poser require phpunit/phpunit
```

Afterwards, calling `phpunit` on the shell will work as expected.